# Select * from MyTable where name='%Jack%' in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, select

i want to write a SELECT in MySQL like this SELECT in MS-SQL

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE name='%Jack%'
```

and this answer:

```
+--------+
| Jack   |
+--------+
| Ajack  | 
+--------+
| jackA  | 
+--------+
| AJackA |
+--------+
```

in MySql How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **LIKE** operator with **LOWER** keyword to match the name with a value.

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE LOWER(name)  LIKE '%jack%';
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `LIKE`

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE name LIKE '%Jack%'
```

And if you use a case-sensitive collation for your data you can change that for your query

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE name LIKE '%Jack%' collate utf8_general_ci
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89141/2)

Answer (score 1):

If SQL `LIKE` clause is used along with % characters then it will work like a meta character (*) in Unix while listing out all the files or directories at command prompt.

Without a % character `LIKE` clause is very similar to equal sign alongwith `WHERE` clause.

**Syntax:**

Here is generic SQL syntax of SELECT command along with LIKE clause to fetch data from MySQL table:

```
SELECT field1, field2,...fieldN table_name1, table_name2...
WHERE field1 LIKE condition1 [AND [OR]] filed2 = 'somevalue'
```

**In your case Use**

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE name LIKE '%Jack%'
```

Comment: remove backtick around `LIKE`. it will cause syntax error on your query.

Answer (score 1):

Read official documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Your worked variant is `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE name = 'Jack'`;

Or using like Your worked variant is `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE name LIKE '%Jack%';`